# Is it possible to let two kernel drivers to regist on one PCIe bus with ths same vendor and device ID

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I'm trying to create two linux kernel driver to access the same PCIe device(use the same vendor and device ID). 
The ideal is to use FPGA to control meny sensors(light sensor, ... ) and mapping control method to PCIe endpoint.
The powerful CPU(x86) will access sensors by registers thru PCIe interface to FPGA.
But, I don't have any experience about PCIe.
So, does anyone can give an advice to me.

Is this concept correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong - I bet all those leds and sensors connect via standard buses like I2C and PMBus. Make your FPGA present an I2C controller via PCIe, the PCIe driver registers as Linux I2C bus provider and than the leds, sensors etc. drivers are I2C drivers that talk to different devices over I2C bus

Comment: Yes, you are right. I implement an I2C controller on FPGA and export it to the PCIe endpoint. So my CPU can access sensor thru PCIe bus.

Comment: I already implement a prototype with mfd (multi-function driver). Mfd can get resource with  PCI vendor and device ID and dispatch resource into each driver (I2C controller, UART controller...). That is exactly what I need.
Thanks for your advice.